# How can I optimize my code? And to equate the angle of the endangle with the cursor circle

Tags: qt, qml

first I want to optimize this code,
Secondly, Endangle does not work properly and I want the angle of the canvas to be the same as the angle of the cursor circle.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE9lf.jpg)

My goal in this property is that I want to customize the objects and the objects are ready when designing the project, I want to write a program like Dopsoft that is used for HMI and I want the objects to be ready.

Dial.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQml 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: dial_item

    property string dial_fontStyle: "Calibri"
    property real dial_x: 400
    property real dial_y: 200
    property real dial_width: 200
    property real dial_height: dial_width
    property real dial_value: 10
    property real dial_textSize: 55
    property string dial_textColor: "white"//"#29b6f6"
    property string dial_backColor: "orange"
    property bool dial_textBold: false
    property string dial_borderColorPress: "gray"
    property string dial_borderColorNotPress: "yellow"
    property real dial_borderWidth: 2
    property string dial_strokeColor: "#29b6f6"
    property real dial_strokeWidth: 10
    property real dial_widthCursor: 16
    property real dial_heightCursor: dial_widthCursor
    property string dial_cursorColorPress: "blue"
    property string dial_cursorColorNotPress: "#21be2b"
    property real dial_cursorRadius: 8

    property real dial_shadowGlowRadius: 2
    property real dial_shadowSpread: 0.8
    property string dial_shadowColor: "black"
    property real dial_shadowRadius: dial_width / 2


    // shdow for delay button
    RectangularGlow {
        id: effect
        width: dial_width
        height: dial_height
        x: dial_x
        y: dial_y
        glowRadius: dial_shadowGlowRadius
        spread: dial_shadowSpread
        color: dial_shadowColor
        cornerRadius: dial_shadowRadius
    }


    FontLoader { id: fontStyle; name: dial_fontStyle }

    // @disable-check M129
    Dial {
        id: dial
        x:dial_x
        y: dial_y
        width: dial_width
        height: dial_height

        Text {
            id: txt
            text: qsTr(dial_value + "%")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.family: fontStyle.name
            font.pixelSize: dial_textSize
            font.bold: dial_textBold
            color: dial_textColor
        }

        background: Rectangle {
            id: rect
            x: dial.width / 2 - width / 2
            y: dial.height / 2 - height / 2
            width: Math.max(64, Math.min(dial.width, dial.height))
            height: width
            color: dial_backColor
            radius: width / 2
            border.color: dial.pressed ? dial_borderColorPress : dial_borderColorNotPress
            border.width: dial_borderWidth
            opacity: dial.enabled ? 1 : 0.3
            Canvas {
                id: canvas
                anchors.fill: parent

                Connections {
                    target: dial
                    onAngleChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
                }

                onPaint: {
                    var ctx = getContext("2d")
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
                    ctx.strokeStyle = dial_strokeColor
                    ctx.lineWidth = dial_strokeWidth
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    var startAngle = Math.PI / 5 * 3.6
                    var endAngle = startAngle + ((280 * (Math.PI/180)) * (dial.angle / 0.87))
                    if (endAngle > 0.87) endAngle = 0.87
                    ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2 - ctx.lineWidth / 2 - 2, startAngle, endAngle)
                    ctx.stroke()
                }
            }
        }
        handle: Rectangle {
            id: handleItem
            x: dial.background.x + dial.background.width / 2 - width / 2
            y: dial.background.y + dial.background.height / 2 - height / 2
            width: dial_widthCursor
            height: dial_heightCursor
            color: dial.pressed ? dial_cursorColorPress : dial_cursorColorNotPress
            radius: dial_cursorRadius
            antialiasing: true
            opacity: dial.enabled ? 1 : 0.3

            transform: [
                Translate {
                    y: -Math.min(dial.background.width, dial.background.height) * 0.4 + handleItem.height / 2
                },
                Rotation {
                    angle: dial.angle
                    origin.x: handleItem.width / 2
                    origin.y: handleItem.height / 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow MReza!

There are several problems with your code.

1. The naming convention looks odd to me. You don't really need dial_ prefix when you are defining properties inside the `Dial`.
2. It's a good idea to use `alias` properties. They exist to solve a problem. So I recommend you to [read more about it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases) from the Qt documentation.
3. You don't really need the a root item of `Item` type for adding the shadow effect. As you are already defining a custom background for the `Dial`, you can put that `RectangularGlow` effect inside the background item. Now, the resulting component, will be more like the original `Dial` component and the user will have direct access to properties, signals and methods of the original `Dial` component.
4. The `Dial` component has an `angle` property. It means that you won't need any calculations for the `endAngle`. Anyway, the `0` degree definition is different is the Dial and the `Canvas`. They have a `90` degrees difference that should be deducted in our calculations.
5. The `FontLoader` is not intended to be in a component design.

The result could be like below. I did not take too much time to optimize it further. I'm pretty sure that it will take some time from you to analyze all changes. But it worth it.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQml 2.12


Dial {
    id: dial

    implicitWidth: 200
    implicitHeight: 200

    property color strokeColor: "#29b6f6"
    property real strokeWidth: 10

    property real cursorWidth: 16
    property real cursorHeight: 16
    property real cursorRadius: 16

    property color cursorPressedColor: "gray"
    property color cursorReleasedColor: "yellow"

    property alias fontFamily: txt.font.family
    property alias fontPixelSize: txt.font.pixelSize
    property alias fontBold : txt.font.bold
    property alias textColor : txt.color
    property alias backColor : rect.color
    property alias borderWidth: rect.border.width

    property real shadowRadius: effect.glowRadius
    property real shadowSpread: effect.spread
    property string shadowColor: effect.color


    Text {
        id: txt
        text: Math.round(dial.value * 100.0) + "%"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.family: 'Calibri'
        font.pixelSize: dial.width / 4
        font.bold: false
        color: "white"
    }

    background: Item{

        RectangularGlow {
            id: effect
            anchors.fill: parent
            glowRadius: 2
            spread: 0.8
            color: "black"
            cornerRadius: dial.width
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            x: dial.width / 2 - width / 2
            y: dial.height / 2 - height / 2
            width: Math.max(64, Math.min(dial.width, dial.height))
            height: width
            color: "orange"
            radius: width / 2
            border.color: dial.pressed ? cursorPressedColor : cursorReleasedColor
            border.width: 2
            opacity: dial.enabled ? 1 : 0.3
            Canvas {
                id: canvas
                anchors.fill: parent

                Connections {
                    target: dial
                    function onAngleChanged(){
                        canvas.requestPaint()
                    }
                }

                onPaint: {
                    var ctx = getContext("2d")
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
                    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
                    ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    var startAngle = (-140 - 90) * (Math.PI/180.0)
                    var endAngle = (dial.angle - 90)  * (Math.PI/180.0)
                    if (endAngle > 0.87) endAngle = 0.87
                    ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2 - ctx.lineWidth / 2 - 2, startAngle, endAngle)
                    ctx.stroke()
                }
            }
        }


    }
    handle: Rectangle {
        id: handleItem
        x: dial.background.x + dial.background.width / 2 - width / 2
        y: dial.background.y + dial.background.height / 2 - height / 2
        width: cursorWidth
        height: cursorHeight
        color: dial.pressed ? cursorPressedColor : cursorReleasedColor
        radius: cursorRadius
        antialiasing: true
        opacity: dial.enabled ? 1 : 0.3

        transform: [
            Translate {
                y: -Math.min(dial.background.width, dial.background.height) * 0.4 + handleItem.height / 2
            },
            Rotation {
                angle: dial.angle
                origin.x: handleItem.width / 2
                origin.y: handleItem.height / 2
            }
        ]
    }

}
```